# Вместо InnoDB использовать MyISAM

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.
В MySQL 5.5 и выше, по умолчанию таблицы создаются на движке InnoDB.
Как сделать, чтобы после создания БД. Таблицы в ней создавались MyISAM?

Comment: Для каждой таблицы в директиве CREATE TABLE указывать движок MyISAM

Comment: А можно без этого обойтись? Чтобы по умолчанию создавались таблицы на движке MyISAM?

Comment: @tfox, несмотря на предложенный ниже способ, я настоятельно рекомендую указывать движок в самом create table (автоматизируя, конечно, это действие, если оно выполняется скриптом). Есть принцип explicit is better than implicit (явное лучше неявного), суть которого заключается в том, что без указания настроек по умолчанию мы можем на них лишь полагаться и не знаем, какими будут реальные настройки; в частности, заглянувший в середину скрипта пользователь решит, что движок - innodb. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал (при наличии достаточного времени, конечно) прописывать такие вещи явно.

Comment: Согласен. Но как тогда лучше поступить? Если необходимо устанавливать вордпресс не один раз, на сервера с MySQL? С учетом того, что исходники вордпресса постоянно меняются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET default_storage_engine=MYISAM;
```

Если в самом начале скрипта создания базы данных поставить этот ключ, то для данной сессии, таблицы будут создаваться с движком MYISAM по умолчанию. [Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engine-setting.html)